# Installation Guidelines for SharePoint 2010 on windows 2008 R2 Server wth SQLServer

Tags: installation

I just created a VM of Windows 2008 R2 (Standard) server and installed SQLServer 2008 Standard edition. Now before moving towards Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise I would to ask few things.

i work for a bank so we do have domain environment with multi farming like Exchange, SQLServer are on seperate servers. But I want to learn sharepoint on my own 4GB laptop and offcoruse i cant come up with the exchange so to come up with the similar environment what can i do?

1. Create AD in windows 2008 server?
2. Install free mail servers i.e AXIGEN
3. Create Windows XP client VM

is this the right sequence I should follow?

Now to keep the above mentioned things what advise u guys can give a newbie like me so i can create a good working environment and wouldnt have problems later on if I create the same in my office for UAT and production. Any guidelines for the installation.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has only 4GB of RAM there is no chance you will be able to run SharePoint Enterprise inside a VM. You are trying to put a Grizzly bear on a child's bike. The  first thing you need to do is to get a better laptop or to put your VM on a server host in your company. I know it may sound insane to your manager but that's the truth! :)

If this is your first encounter with SharePoint I would recommend downloading [SharePoint IW Demo VM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=751fa0d1-356c-4002-9c60-d539896c66ce&displaylang=en) that has everything preconfigured so you can focus on SharePoint from start. You need a minimum of 6GB of RAM, and fast disk (think SSD) to run this machine.

1) If you want to create your own machine, I would recommend running in an separate AD. The best option is to connect to a test domain operated by your IT department (e.g. BANKTEST domain) so you do not have to worry about it. Once you have secured proper resources, read [Deploy a single server with SQL Server (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx) to install SharePoint in your own machine in BANKTEST domain.

2) If Exchange is not available in test domain you can check [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) as an alternative.

3) You can use your laptop OS as client, I think XP VM is not needed.

Comment: Agreed - I use a machine with 6GB RAM and an SSD and it runs a SP2010 VM (4GB RAM assigned) adequately. Our work server has 32GB of RAM but that's for shared dev :-).